# How to fix broken packages on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, apt, package-management

I have a Ubuntu 18.10 server, and recently tried to update `git`. I keep getting errors that a number of packages are not properly installed.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd64
 libpaper-utils
 unattended-upgrades
 libgs9:amd64
 ghostscript
```

Then I ran `dpkg --configure -a` and see the same errors. I want to be careful and not hose my system, but how can I fix these errors?

```
~ $ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
~ $ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
~ $ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libpaper1:amd64 (1.1.24+nmu5ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libpaper1:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpaper1:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpaper-utils:
 libpaper-utils depends on libpaper1; however:
  Package libpaper1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libpaper-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up unattended-upgrades (1.5ubuntu3.18.10.4) ...
dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 installed unattended-upgrades package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgs9:amd64:
 libgs9:amd64 depends on libpaper1; however:
  Package libpaper1:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgs9:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ghostscript:
 ghostscript depends on libgs9 (= 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.10.9); however:
  Package libgs9:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ghostscript (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpaper1:amd64
 libpaper-utils
 unattended-upgrades
 libgs9:amd64
 ghostscript
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

*EDIT*

In response to @Stefan Skoglund's question:

```
~ $ sudo apt-cache policy libpaper1
libpaper1:
  Installed: 1.1.24+nmu5ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.1.24+nmu5ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.24+nmu5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

~ $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow libpaper1
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libpaper1 is broken or not fully installed
```

*EDIT 2*

Throwing caution to the wind, I closed my eyes, crossed by fingers and tried this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libpaper1:amd64 libpaper-utils unattended-upgrades libgs9:amd64 ghostscript
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

It magically worked.

Bounty is still available to someone who could explain what happened here and what the best practice / troubleshooting hints would be.

Comment: You could try using "aptitude" - the curses based interface to apt.  It's pretty good (not perfect) at proposing solutions to installation problems . . . and you can always cancel if you don't find one to your liking.

Comment: Why on earth would this be voted down? Could the down voters please add a comment explaining their choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happened here is that the post-install script of the libpaper1 package was broken, and exited with an error during the install process. This should not happen, because it breaks the package state just as you experienced, which is why it is a good idea to report the error to the package maintainer. See the [ReportingBugs wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for details.

Your options are the following:

**Remove the package and wait for a fix**. This is what probably happened in your case: by the time you decided to purge the libpaper1 package, it got fixed, and the new install succeeded.

It should be noted that no matter if there is an upgraded package available, it will not be downloaded while the package state is broken. So you have to remove the package, and reinstall it.

**Repair the post-install script**. This is an alternative if you really, absolutely need that package, and you don't want to wait until a fix. You really need to know what you're doing (shell programming knowledge is a must), but repairing the script is usually straightforward.

Every package can have a pre-installation and a post-installation script, these dwell in the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory, and are named `package[:arch].preinst` and `package[:arch].postinst`. These are executed prior to, and after the installation, respectively [*].

In your case the post-installation script failed, which means that the package got installed (so the files was extracted), the only thing left was to execute the post-install script. So what you need to do is to run the script (`libpaper1:amd64.postinst`) from a root terminal, and record the line in which the error occurred. Repairing the script is usually trivial from here, but be sure to understand what the script was trying to do, since it may be possible that the failed command was crucial for the package. Do try to actually repair the script (for example, appending `|| true` to the end of the line works, but may not be the best idea).

If the script runs without error, the

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

command will configure all pending packages, and runs the postinstall script in the process, restoring the package state.

[*] The actual process is a little bit more complicated of course; if you want to know what happens exactly during install/removal, see the description of the `install`, `configure`, and `remove` actions in the dpkg(1) man page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try apt-get install -f?

I already had such problems when I had to work on servers with different package sources.

The solutions were different.
In general, you should avoid mixing different package sources.

If packages with the apt parameter -t <...> were installed, then it helped to install all problematic packages with the help of this parameter.

Sometimes, however, I had to remove the packages first.

But I also had the case that I had to work with -Force parameters.Did you try apt-get install -f?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andre, I haven't tried force as I as worried I will break the server. What do you mean by mixing package sources?

Comment: For example, mixing package sources of different Ubuntu versions. If packages from different versions are then installed, dependency checking will cause problems.If you have not changed anything in your package sources, this should not be the case. Imagine you have Ubuntu 18.04, but if you installed a package from 19.04, then there may be problems if the package from 19.04 requires newer versions of dependent packages than 18.04.serves

Comment: I'm not sure how I would even do that. It's Ubuntu 18.10 ... could I be accidentally installing 19.x packages?

Answer (score 0):

Short anwer that worked for me

```
sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/*.dat
```

then, update and upgrade flawlessly